# Как записать строки из файла в коллекцию строк textBox?

Tags: c#, textbox

У меня есть текстовый документ, в котором в столбик прописаны слова. Я получаю и вывожу эти слова так:

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"F:\VS Projects\Со звёздочкой\diceware.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    textBox1.AppendText(line + "\t\t");
}
```

Но тогда выходит, что я не добавляю в коллекцию, а просто переношу курсор. В дальнейшем мне нужно перебирать строки, чтобы получить определённое слово. Как записывать в коллекцию?

Пробовал делать так:

```
textBox1.Lines[0] = line;
```

Но тогда выдаёт исключение System.IndexOutOfRangeException.

Comment: List<String> strings = new List();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прочитать в массив можно одной строчкой кода.

```cs
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"F:\VS Projects\Со звёздочкой\diceware.txt");
```

Далее можно записать это все в текстбокс так же одной строчкой

```cs
textBox1.Text = string.Join("\t\t", lines);
```

Ну и так же можно работать с этим массивом, например

```cs
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    textBox1.AppendText(line + "\t\t");
}
```

или

```cs
textBox1.Text = lines[0];
```

или

```cs
lines[0] = "text";
```

Либо преобразовать в коллекцию и изменять ее состав

```cs
List<string> list = lines.ToList();
list.Add("text");
```

И записать ее в файл

```cs
File.WriteAllLines("file.txt", list.ToArray());
```